# Pre-trained VGG-16 in MATLAB and PyTorch Same?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, pytorch, vgg-net

I have been trying to figure this out for some time but i am still a bit unsure. Does the PyTorch pre-trained VGG-16 (torchvision model) have exactly the same weights as the MATLAB pre-trained VGG-16?

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested to find out, just take the norm of the weights in both libraries. I think they should be same.